# libssh and multi-threading

Tags: c++, multithreading, libssh

I was wondering if libssh supports multi-threaded applications. In my C++ code, I create a SSH session which will be shared among multiple threads. Each thread requests a shell, run a command and calls ssh_channel_read_timeout in a while loop to receive all output messages. Is this scenario supported by libssh?

I found this [doc](http://api.libssh.org/master/libssh_tutor_threads.html), but I was wondering if the documentation is up to date.

Comment: https://www.libssh.org/communication/ - why are you asking this question here, instead of the libssh@libssh.org's mailing list?

Comment: More than 100 questions are tagged with libssh in SO and I thought that SO would be a suitable place. Moreover, developers usually monitor the relevant tags in SO and answer them. I will also post this in the libssh mailing list later. Thanks!